# Bouncing problem

Tags: debouncing

I'm trying to create a debouncing module for a button. I looked through the information and decided to use a shift register. Looking through all the debouncing examples, I noticed that they usually use counters to "wait" for the values to become sufficient (for example, the counter is initially 0 and they increment it and wait until it is, say, 99999). But each implementation has different values for this counter, and they seem completely random. How do I determine what value I need to set the counter to? Or where can I find a better explanation of how long I need to wait until I can consider the values in my register to be sufficient? (sometimes it’s written like 20ms, but I still don’t understand how they found it and why exactly 20ms and not 21 or 19 or 27)

Comment: who is asking you to create the debounce module?

Comment: do you understand what a debounce module actually does? ... what are you denouncing?

Comment: This is an assignment for the course. I understand perfectly well what the debouncer’s task is and why this happens and so on. I just don't understand how people define how long this Bouncing lasts

Comment: I'm debouncing a button

Comment: think about two factors ... `length of switch bounce` and `response delay after switch press`

Comment: Have you got the part number of the button? Sometimes the button or switch datasheet shows the bounce time information.

Comment: No, unfortunately I don't have one. But anyway, as far as I understood, "bouncing time" depends on a certain button and its characteristics. Is that correct?

Comment: Because if so, then it turns out that I asked completely idiotic question

Comment: It's not, or we would all be idiots before we knew. @jsotola 's comment about length and response is valid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well the debouncing time must be long enough to filter out the actual length how long the buttom will bounce. If button outputs a scratchy signal for 5ms when new, the debounce period must be 5ms plus any margin how long the scratchy period is after the button is used for say 10 years or 1 million times.

It can be of course much longer, but depending on what the button does, a 100ms period is awfully long if user wants to e.g. set time for a clock, as it limits how long you must keep the button pressed or released between events.

Another thing is that depends what the button does is do you debounce only the press or the release part or both.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm debouncing the press part

Comment: I have thought about debounce release but read nothing about it - when would it be necessary?

Comment: @MiNiMe Well if you have determined that a button is reliably pushed now as it has been 10ms pressed constantly, if the release is not debounced, any moment of unpushed detection and then making contact again for 10ms will be determined as a new push, even if you as the user kept the button down all the time.

Comment: @MiNiMe **You** know whether a button is pushed or released, but how does logic know? It can only tell by logic states (high or low). While bouncing, logic pulses back and forth many times, so you cannot tell if bouncing is the result of a push or a release. Only after bouncing ceases can logic reliably determine if the button state is "pushed" or "released". Your de-bouncing method must deal with both, even though action is taken only on "push" and none on "release"

Comment: Thanks guys, the articles and videos I have studied focus on the initial debounce, and the falling edge didn't look like it needed any attention. Now I know it *can* happen.